# Gnome-Control-Panel crashes while trying to access Online Accounts

Tags: gnome, empathy

Running Ubuntu Gnome 13.04 x64.
I set up Empathy with Facebook and Google Accounts, and I sent my PC to Standby, then it showed my FB Accounts was disconnected.
Couldn't open Online Accounts (of Gnome) since then.
When I start `gnome-control-panel` via Terminal, and go to Online Accounts, I get this:

```
beryju@beryju-i3:~/.config$ gnome-control-center online-accounts
**
ERROR:empathy-user-info.c:252:fill_contact_info_grid: assertion failed: (spec != NULL)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this workaround:

In order to overcome this I set my status to "Offline", after that I am able to manage accounts by pressing "F4" than I change my status back to "Available"

(from https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center-signon/+bug/1174936/comments/5)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with

```
sudo apt-get remove empathy shotwell
#Add the account again
sudo apt-get install empathy shotwell
```